# How do I get started with J2ME?

Tags: java-me, java

i am new to J2ME. Please tell me how can I install it and where from.
What else do I have to download to install J2ME with JDK.

Comment: Run for the hills! While you still have a chance!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you are a beginner, I recommend starting with [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/) IDE. Download the version that includes the Mobility Pack. There are many tutorials available for developing mobile applications with Netbeans.

You may also need the [WTK](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/) (don't remember if it comes with Netbeans),

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to start out with J2ME development (such as with MIDP) if you haven't done any Java programming before. You might want to start with this [NetBeans quickstart](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/quickstart.html).

There are also a bunch of emulators, requiring some configuration to do on your IDE (e.g. Netbeans or Eclipse). This is because different cell-phone manufacturers have their own implementation SDK's on J2ME (e.g. [SonyEricsson](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/site/global/docstools/java/p_java.jsp)).

Answer (score 2):

Tools

The basic tool for j2me development is [WTK](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/)(Wireless tool kit) from SUN which contains the emulator and other libraries needed for development. WTK also contains utilities for signing ,preverifying ,network monitoring tools.The IDEs like [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org) and [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) are having plug ins for j2me development. These plugins will integrate the WTK and libraries.
For netbeans all are bundled into one package ,so easy to install and configure. For Eclipse you have to install the [MTJ](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/mtj/)(mobile tools for java) plugin.

You can check both IDEs and select the one which your most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing like a complete package. You need a basic setup and optional device-provider packages (mostly emulators).

***Basic setup:***

- **[SUN WTK (includes basic J2ME SDK)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137162.html)**
- **[Eclipse Plugin](http://eclipseme.org/)**

***Optional packages:***

- **[Sony](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/technology/java/sdk)**
- **[Motorola](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/sdks/)**
- **[Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Library/Tools_and_downloads/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need the Sun wireless toolkit. You need this for the libraries, and also to 'preverify' your class files, otherwise they won't load on a mobile VM.

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=201507

Answer (score -1):

You can download J2ME from the [Sun Microsystems](http://www.sun.com/) website