# Some questions for j2me

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-me

I do have some questions which always confuse me a lot.

(1) Why when we install j2me, we have to install jdk first? [for my understanding, they are independent 2 versions, one is of embedded, another is for desktop application]

(2) How to install the j2me environment into the phone or embedded device? Do we need to install the jdk firstly? (It seems that jdk cannot be installed on phone and embedded devices).

(3) what is the relationship among j2me, j9, phoneMe, jamVM...?  When use this in the embedded devices, the pre-requisites is also the JDK? (you have to install the jdk firstly?)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Which phone are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

A very rough outline...

1. You need the JDK to compile java code - J2ME provides an API for your application, but no compiler.
2. Your target devices will come with a JVM and J2ME environment built in, so no need to worry about this directly as a developer.
3. I think you've got two questions in here.  You don't need the JDK on the target device; only when compiling your app.  But see 1. - you do need the JDK to compile your app.

[J9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_J9) and [JamVM](http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/) are VMs I'm not familiar with; hopefully others will chip in.  Likewise on [phoneMe](https://phoneme.dev.java.net/).

See also the related questions on SO (over at the right of this page), especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650033/how-do-i-get-started-with-j2me).

Answer (score 0):

For missing part,

[J9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_J9) is JVM implementation by IBM. [phoneME](https://phoneme.dev.java.net/) is open source implementation of Java ME (CLDC, CDC) by Sun Microsystems. I don't know about JamVM but, I can find it [from web](http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/). It looks like SE JVM for light weight implementation.

Answer (score 0):

3.

1. J9:
   J9 is a Java Virtual Machine developed by IBM. The J9 VM is the basis of multiple IBM Java offerings, including WebSphere Micro Edition, as well as the basis of all IBM Java Development kits since version 5. 
   The design of the J9 VM has been aimed at portability to different platforms, as well as scaling from mobile phones all the way to zSeries mainframes.
   2.JamVM:
   JamVM is a new Java Virtual Machine which conforms to the JVM specification version 2 (blue book). In comparison to most other VM's (free and commercial) it is extremely small, with a stripped executable on PowerPC of only ~220K, and Intel 200K. However, unlike other small VMs (e.g. KVM) it is designed to support the full specification, and includes support for object finalisation, Soft/Weak/Phantom References, class-unloading, the Java Native Interface (JNI) and the Reflection API.
2. PhoneME
   A phone is …
   One of many possible sounds in the languages of the world.
   The smallest identifiable unit found in a stream of speech.
   Pronounced in a defined way.
   Represented between brackets by convention.
   Example:

[b], [j], [o]

A phoneme is …
A contrastive unit in the sound system of a particular language.
A minimal unit that serves to distinguish between meanings of words.
Pronounced in one or more ways, depending on the number of allophones.
represented between slashes by convention.
Example:

/b/, /j/, /o/